# variable can't get in view html of angular 5 rest full

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a problem about showing a variable in Angular 5. the problem is that the variable is undefined outside of the subscribe (in detail.component.ts). when I test this variable in subscribe, the console of browser show the true result but over subscribe it show "undefined". 
My goal is to display the detail of a person according to the parameter url which is an identifier of this person by calling the corresponding service . Please, help me because it's important. thank you.

It's my back end made in node.js. index.js

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

//start mysql connection
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost', //mysql database host name
  user     : 'root', //mysql database user name
  password : '', //mysql database password
  database : 'essai' //mysql database name
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('You are now connected with mysql database...')
})
//end mysql connection

app.use(cors());

//start body-parser configuration
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
//end body-parser configuration

//create app server
var server = app.listen(3000,  "127.0.0.1", function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

});

//rest api to get all personnes
app.get('/personne/getall', function (req, res) {
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM personne ORDER BY id', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});
//rest api to get a single personne data
app.get('/personne/:id', function (req, res) {
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM personne WHERE id=?', [req.params.id], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});

//rest api to create a new customer record into mysql database
app.post('/personne/add', function (req, res) {
   var params  = req.body;
   console.log(params);
   connection.query('INSERT INTO personne SET ?', params, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});

//rest api to update record into mysql database
app.put('/personne/edit', function (req, res) {
   connection.query('UPDATE `personne` SET `nom`=?,`age`=? WHERE `id`=?', [req.body.nom, req.body.age, req.body.id], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
});

//rest api to delete record from mysql database
app.delete('/personne/delete', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body);
   connection.query('DELETE FROM `personne` WHERE `id`=?', [req.body.id], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.end('Personne has been deleted!');
    });
});
```

it's the service. personne.service.ts in front end

```
    import { Personne } from '../modeles/personne';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonneService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll(): Observable<Personne[]> {
    return this.http.get<Personne[]>('http://localhost:3000/personne/getall');
  }

  getById(id: number): Observable<Personne> {
    return this.http.get<Personne>('http://localhost:3000/personne/' + id);
  }

  add(personne: Personne): Observable<Personne> {
    return this.http.post<Personne>('http://localhost:3000/personne/add/', personne);
  }

  edit(personne: Personne): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.put<void>('http://localhost:3000/personne/edit/' + personne.id, personne);
  }

  supp(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/personne/delete/' + id);
  }
}
```

it's model entity

```
export class Personne {
  id: number;
  nom: string;
  age: number;
}
```

it's component personne. personne.component.ts

```
import { Personne } from '../../../modeles/personne';
import { PersonneService } from '../../../services/personne.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-personne',
  templateUrl: './personne.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personne.component.css']
})
export class PersonneComponent implements OnInit {

  personnes: Personne[];

  constructor(private personneService: PersonneService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAll();
  }

  getAll() {
    this.personneService.getAll()
          .subscribe( data => {
            this.personnes = data;
          });
  }

}
```

it's personne view. personne.component.html

```
<a routerLink="/personne/add"><button>+New personne</button></a>
<h3>Liste des personnes</h3>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th><th>Nom</th><th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let personne of personnes">
            <td>
                {{personne.id}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{personne.nom}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{personne.age}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a routerLink="/personne/edit/{{personne.id}}"><button>Edit</button></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button (click)="supp(personne)">Delete</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a routerLink="/personne/detail/{{personne.id}}"><button>Detail</button></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

it's detail component and this is the problem. detail.component.ts

```
import { Personne } from '../../../modeles/personne';
import { PersonneService } from '../../../services/personne.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.css']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() personne: Personne;

  id: number;
  constructor(
     private personneService: PersonneService,
     private route: ActivatedRoute,
     private location: Location
   ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detail();
  }

  detail(): void {
    this.personneService.getById(this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe(personne => this.personne = personne);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

}
```

it's detail view. detail.component.html

```
<h2>Detail d'une personne</h2>
<div *ngIf="personne">  
<table>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Id</strong></td><td><strong>:{{personne.id}}</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Nom</strong></td><td>:{{personne.nom}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
        <td><strong>Age</strong></td><td>:{{personne.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<button (click)="goBack()">Retour</button>
```

it's routing module

```
import { AddComponent } from './pages/personne/add/add.component';
import { DetailComponent } from './pages/personne/detail/detail.component';
import { EditComponent } from './pages/personne/edit/edit.component';
import { PersonneComponent } from './pages/personne/personne/personne.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/personne', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'personne', component: PersonneComponent },
  { path: 'personne/add', component: AddComponent },
  { path: 'personne/edit/:id', component: EditComponent },
  { path: 'personne/detail/:id', component: DetailComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to utilize `Personne` in `DetailComponent` as an `@Input()`. This is incorrect as you are not passing a `Personne` object to the each `DetailComponent` component in `PersonneComponent`. You'd need to remove `@Input()` from `DetailComponent` as you are populating that `personne` object async using `HttpClient` service methods.

Passing data from a [parent to child](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding) using '@Input()` would look something like the following, which wouldn't be what you want given the routing structure you are using of a separate detail page/view:

```
<td><app-detail [personne]="personne"></app-detail></td>
```

Also, ideally you shouldn't directly retrieve values from `ActivatedRoute` as this detail component is reused. You would need to use RxJS operators such as `switchMap` to retrieve the id and pass that to service method `getById`. Below is an example using RxJS 5.5+. This is effectively a situation directly described in the Router [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action). Notice, you'd need to import `ParamMap` as well as `switchMap` RxJS operator.

```
import { Personne } from '../../../modeles/personne';
import { PersonneService } from '../../../services/personne.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.css']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  personne: Personne;

  id: number;
  constructor(
     private personneService: PersonneService,
     private route: ActivatedRoute,
     private location: Location
   ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.detail();
  }

  detail(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.personneService.getById(params.get('id')))
      )
      .subscribe(personne => this.personne = personne);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

}
```

If you are using an older version of RxJS (< 5.5), you would simply statically import `switchMap` and chain the methods instead:

```
detail(): void {
  this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.personneService.getById(params.get('id')))
    .subscribe(personne => this.personne = personne);
}
```

Another potential issue is your MySQL call for getting an item by `id`. That `SELECT * FROM personne WHERE id=?` statement is probably returning an array rather than a single object. It doesn't look like anywhere in the Express or Angular code you are extracting the item at the first index or similar. Have you checked the return type of data from that Express endpoint?

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.personne=new Personne();
    this.detail();
  }
```

hope it's help

Comment: You should include an explanation on why you believe you answer will solve the problem.

Comment: I have same problem (undefined) when I don't instantiate my object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers, they help me and resolve my problem. the problem in this programme is that the return of requete one nodejs, it returns an array data and I change my code this.personneService.getById(this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe(personne => this.personne = personne); 
to
this.personneService.getById(this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe(personne => this.personne = personne[0]);